# Performance difference between a named function import vs the whole lib in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import

I received an interesting code review comment and I wanted to know how import types in components, hooks, etc. affect performance.

The question is whether there is a performance difference between the two examples below and why?

```
1. import _ from 'lodash'; // then, use _.isEmpty;
2. import { isEmpty } from 'lodash/isEmpty';
```

My understanding was that the import is a reference of that function that gets bundled the same in the end - but I don't know too much about it.

Perhaps, another possible context to consider - may be local hot-reloading.

Comment: The second should be `import isEmpty from 'lodash/isEmpty';` and yes, there is a difference since it will only import `isEmpty`, not the whole bundle of Lodash of which you'd use only one item. That's not down to "performance" as it's not CPU cycles that you save but memory.